# How do you make the x-value of a Numbers graph start with a number that is not 0

Tags: numbers

The simple question is, how do you make the x-value of a Numbers graph start with a number that is not 0. The x-axis of my graph is time, and it starts with 30 seconds, but the graph that numbers created starts with 0 seconds, which creates a large gap between x=0 and x=30. How could I remove that gap?

Comment: Which chart type are you using: 2D column, 2D line, 2D scatter, etc? You could get better help if you could post a screenshot of a sample of your data and the chart you have created so far.

Comment: 2D scatter is what I am using @Alper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the minimum and maximum values the x-axis can take in a 2D scatter chart in Numbers. Just select the chart and change the Scale options in Format > Axis > Value (X) sidebar as per necessary as shown in the example below. Hope this helps.

[image]