# How do you make the x-value of a Numbers graph start with a number that is not 0 -- repeat question, but for 2d bar chart

Tags: mac, numbers

the question was already asked, with a great response, BUT I'm trying to use a 2d bar chart, and the Scale Max / Min is locked with 'auto'

[QUESTION & ANSWER](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439095/how-do-you-make-the-x-value-of-a-numbers-graph-start-with-a-number-that-is-not-0)

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum or maximum setting in the x-axis settings for a bar or column chart like for the scatter chart in the Q&A you have referred to because the x-axis is assumed to be showing a [categoric variable](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/1/1.1/1.1.1) by default in such charts. In general, categoric variables, unlike quantitative variables, can not be sorted or ranked and therefore set limits for.